# Passing a structure to a COM object in a safe way

Tags: windows, com

I am trying to write a Windows 64-bit COM object that can accept structures as parameters.  I would like to call this COM object from Python and R.  I would like the COM object to return structures as well.

Questions:

1. It doesn't appear that COM has a standard way of receiving and sending structures.  Is this correct?  If not, please provide a reference or documentation.
2. Assuming one can pass structures, how to do this in a safe way such that it can be called by Python and R with a minimum of hiccups.

Comment: COM supports structures just fine (see the [struct attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/struct)).

Comment: @IInspectable awesome, thanks for the link.